# TabControl renaming in run-time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create simple interface where user can rename tab in TabControl. Problem is that since I can get position of tab by GetTabRect method, I can't set TextBox into a place of tab. Here is the desired effect (from foobar):

[image]

And here is my effect:

[image]

Below I insert my code where I try to make this effect:

```
      private void renameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedTab >= 0 && selectedTab < MainTabs.TabCount)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Rename " + MainTabs.Controls[selectedTab].Text);
            Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString());

            //var CurrentTab = MainTabs.TabPages[selectedTab];
            //TabControl tabControl = MainTabs.Con

            Rectangle rect = MainTabs.GetTabRect(selectedTab);
            Point point = MainTabs.Location;

            Debug.WriteLine(point.ToString() + " " + rect.ToString());

            RenameBox = new TextBox();

            MainTabs.GetControl(selectedTab).Controls.Add(RenameBox);

            //MainTabs

            RenameBox.Show();

            RenameBox.SetBounds(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);


            //MainTab.Controls.Add(RenameBox);
            //this.Controls.Add(RenameBox);
            //components.Add(RenameBox);

            //RenameBox.Location = point;

            //MainTabs.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(RenameBox);

            //MainTabs.GetControl(0).Controls.Add(RenameBox);

            //MainTabs.SelectedTab.

            RenameBox.KeyPress += textBox1_KeyPress;
            //RenameBox.Show();
            //RenameBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            //RenameBox.Focus();
            //RenameBox.SetBounds(.GetTabRect(selectedTab));

        }
    }
```

How should I change the code to be able to rename Tab name in runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetTabRect() returns the position relative to the tab control.  But you are adding the textbox to the tabpage, it is located *below* the tabstrip.  Which is why your screenshot looks like that.  You cannot give the textbox a negative position, it would be clipped.  Ideally you would add it to the tab control, but TabControl explicitly forbids this.  The only other thing you can do is add it the form.

You'll have to calculate the correct position, mapping the tabrect to form coordinates.  And ensure it overlaps the tabcontrol.  Removing it again is surely best done with its Leave event.  Like this:

```
private TextBox AddTextBoxToTab(TabControl tabctl, int index = -1) {
    if (index < 0) index = tabctl.SelectedIndex;
    var rc = tabctl.GetTabRect(index);
    rc = tabctl.RectangleToScreen(rc);
    rc = tabctl.Parent.RectangleToClient(rc);
    var box = new TextBox();
    box.Font = tabctl.Font;
    box.Leave += delegate { box.Dispose(); };
    box.SetBounds(rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height);
    tabctl.Parent.Controls.Add(box);
    box.BringToFront();
    box.Focus();
    return box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would implement this as a lightweight form, positioned over the top of the tab.

[image]

To make a lightweight form, set the following properties:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
Text            = string.Empty;
StartPosition   = FormStartPosition.Manual;
ControlBox      = false;
ShowInTaskbar   = false;
```

A lightweight form can have a larger `TextBox` and could display validation errors with an `ErrorProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

### Oops...

I didn't realize this question was for WinForms until just now (Edit history shows the tag was added later).  I'm going to leave the answer in place though, in case it is useful for anyone wanting to know how to do this with WPF.

---

You can do this rather easily using the MVVM pattern without having to worry about positioning code at all.  [Full Source is available at this link](https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/renamabletabs/src).

[image]

This uses a list of `DocumentVm` with a `Name`, and an `IsRenaming` property.  The `TabControl` has its `ItemsSource` bound to the list of `DocumentVm` so that it has one tab per Document.  The header of the `TabItem` contains a `TextBlock`, a `TextBox`, and `Button`.  When you click the button, the `IsRenaming` flag is toggled.  The `TextBox` and `TextBlock` have their visibility controlled by `IsRenaming` (using a normal, and inverted converter).  So clicking the button lets you edit the tab's title.

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="RenamableTabs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RenamableTabs"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowVm}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        <local:InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="8">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Documents}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRenaming, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRenaming, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <Button Command="{Binding Path=RenameCommand}" Content="R" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowVm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services.Message;

namespace RenamableTabs
{
    class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            _messageService = ServiceManager.GetService<AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services.Message.IMessageService>();
            _messageService.Subscribe<DocumentVm.DocumentRenaming>(message =>
            {
                var m = message as DocumentVm.DocumentRenaming;
                foreach (var documentVm in Documents)
                {
                    documentVm.IsRenaming = documentVm == m.Document;
                }
            });

            Documents = new ObservableCollection<DocumentVm>();

            Documents.Add(new DocumentVm() { Name = "Document 1" });
            Documents.Add(new DocumentVm() { Name = "Document 2" });
            Documents.Add(new DocumentVm() { Name = "Document 3" });
        }

        private IMessageService _messageService;

        public ObservableCollection<DocumentVm> Documents { get; }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get {return _name;}
            set {SetValue(ref _name, value);}
        }

    }
}
```

DocumentVm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Xaml;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Commands;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services.Message;

namespace RenamableTabs
{
    class DocumentVm : ViewModel
    {
        public DocumentVm()
        {
            _messageService = ServiceManager.GetService<AgentOctal.WpfLib.Services.Message.IMessageService>();
        }

        private IMessageService _messageService;

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { SetValue(ref _name, value); }
        }

        private ICommand _renameCommand;
        public ICommand RenameCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _renameCommand ?? (_renameCommand = new SimpleCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    _messageService.SendMessage(new DocumentRenaming() { Document = this });
                }));
            }
        }

        private bool _isRenaming = false;
        public bool IsRenaming
        {
            get { return _isRenaming; }
            set { SetValue(ref _isRenaming, value); }
        }

        public class DocumentRenaming : IMessage
        {
            public DocumentVm Document { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is about windows forms, not wpf

Comment: Well.. there went 20 minutes of my life...  Gotta learn to pay more attention to tags I guess.

Comment: Hah, I just checked the edit history on the question.  It wasn't tagged for Winforms when I read it. I'm feeling better now.

Comment: Happened to me as well in the past :) Even if its not applicable here, the answer still contains a good idea.